# Securely Managing Credentials in Pyspark(secret scope)

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, azure-hdinsight

We are using pyspark - azure HDInsight cluster and running python notebooks. 
Currently We are trying to connect Azure Sqldwh with pyspark to load table from  sql server to pyspark.

Is there any option for us to secure username and password by using config file
Any similar functionality that of databricks secrets in pyspark jupyter notebook.

At present we have hard coded user_name and password in the notebook itself.